# Get position image after Rotation with AffineTransform

Tags: java, awt, java-2d, affinetransform

I use an `AffineTransform` class to transform my image and I need to have a position of image after translation and rotation.  How to achieve that?

```
public void rotateImage(ImageObserver o, Graphics g,  int x, int y) {
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    at.translate(x, y);
    at.rotate(Math.toRadians(deegres),ramie1.getWidth()/2,0);  
    Graphics2D g2 =(Graphics2D) g;
    g2.drawImage(image, at, null);   
}
```

Comment: Does indexing the repositories help?

Comment: The easiest way to find out, is to make a `Point2D` of the original position and transform it!

Comment: `g2.drawImage(image, at, null);` should be `g2.drawImage(image, at, o);`

Comment: OK, i make a Point2D and transform it, thanks.